# Why are the keys of this object strings?

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
request = .ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(object),
    url : 'offline_ajax_queue.php',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        for (var key in response) {
            if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(key, response[key]);
                if(response[key] > -1)
                    removeAction(key);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and in console, response =

```
{1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

and:

```
typeof response[key]  //  "number"
```

Why are the keys `string` and not `number` as well?

```
typeof key  //  "string"
```

Comment: Because they always are. Object properties are strings by definition.

Comment: Object keys are string. Even for arrays indices.

Answer (score 5):

Object property names are **always** strings or symbols, never numbers.

(A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can have keys that are different data types).

Comment: Yes, it is a separate, but related question: Then why do they look like a `number` in the output?

Comment: @David Because the console tries to show a human-friendly output.

Comment: @David, do you mean the console output? That's just browser formatting output. If you converted it to JSON you would see it get's wrapped in quotes to make it a string: `JSON.stringify({1:1})`  would be `{"1":1}`